# How to get the previous pages URI including GET variables

Tags: php

I would like to be able to load the entire URI string *of the previous page* within my PHP, for example:

> The URL that my page is reached **from**: /test.php?test=test

I know that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can get the `test.php` but how to get back the *WHOLE* url, the page name, as well as the `GET` values?

Comment: The rest is in $_GET?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you looking for $_SERVER['`QUERY_STRING'] `?

Comment: I don't know you, but I get the whole url in the HTTP_REFERER, parameters included.

Comment: nope. I want to get back to the previous page and the previous page contain get method therefore i cant use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , any idea how to do?

Comment: @Amarnasan $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] only return me test.php

Comment: edited the question to make the question more clear and to further clarify the english language  and question layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this strictly in PHP, you can do this with Browser back and javascript functionality but this is very easy to be user manipulated. As well as this, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value is only supported now on some systems due to perceived security implications and can also be easily edited by the user, and so is inherently unreliable.

What you can do if you really need a complete page history (even if only of one page) is to load the pages of your site visited, into a `$_SESSION` variable or a database -- something that is not lost from visits to different pages.

So, in your page header you can set an array of pages, `$_SESSION['pages']` and in each page you run, at the top of the page add the page values to the array.

so:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['pages'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
 //structure: shows folder path, filename and query string 
//of the URI used to reach the current page.
```

And to find the previous pages that where accessed, with their query strings (the GET variables), you can do this:

```
$reverse = array_reverse($_SESSION['pages']);
$returnURL = $reverse[1]; 
///previous page address: "/page.php?test=test&goat=yes"
unset($reverse);
```

This is because `$reverse[0]` will be *the page you are currently on* so the preceeding value is `$reverse[1]`.

This code above is somewhat hacky but with pure PHP will give you what you want, without using Browser (cache) history or Javascript.